# Question about Lebesgue-Stieljes measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have a problem with one question about Lebesgue-Stieljes measure. It is as follows:

$ρ(t) = (t − 1)^+$ for all $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and increasing, and the right derivative
$ρ′_+(t) = ρ′(t+) = \textbf{1}_{[1,∞)}(t)$.
Show that the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $m_p(dt) = \textbf{1}_{[1,∞)}(t)dt$
Note $(t-1)^+ = \max\{0, (t-1)\}$

What concerns me is the $dt$-bit in the statement as I'm not quite sure how to interpret it. From what I know, $m_p((s,t])=p(t)-p(s)$ but if as I said, do't really know what the $dt$ stands for.

Thanks!

Comment: $dt$ is ordinary Lebesgue measure and $m_p(dt)$ is a notation for the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by $p$.

Comment: You might "think" of $dt$ denoting a tiny interval $[t,t+dt]$, whose L-S measure is $m_p([t,t+dt])=m(dt)$.  (I mean this as an intuitive way to understand the notation, not as a definition or result to use in calculations.)